# count row number first and then insert new row by condition

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, insert

I need to count the number of rows first after a `group_by` function and add up new row(s) to 6 row if the row number < 6.

My df has three variables (`v1,v2,v3`): `v1 = group name`, `v2 = row number` (i.e., 1,2,3,4,5,6). In the new row(s), I want to repeat the `v1` value, `v2` continue the couting of row number, `v3 = NA`

sample df

```
v1    v2    v3
1     1     79
1     2     32
1     3     53
1     4     33
1     5     76
1     6     11
2     1     32
2     2     42
2     3     44
2     4     12
3     1     22
3     2     12
3     3     12
3     4     67
3     5     32
```

expected output

```
v1    v2    v3
1     1     79
1     2     32
1     3     53
1     4     33
1     5     76
1     6     11
2     1     32
2     2     42
2     3     44
2     4     12
2     5     NA #insert
2     6     NA #insert
3     1     22
3     2     12
3     3     12
3     4     67
3     5     32
3     6     NA #insert
```

I tried to count the row number first by `dplyr`, but I don't know if I can or how can I add this `if else` condition by using the pip. Or is there other easier function?

My code

```
 df %>%
   group_by(v1) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(N=n()) %>%
   if (N < 6) {
   # sth like that?
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
complete(df1, v1, v2)
# A tibble: 18 x 3
#      v1    v2    v3
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1    79
# 2     1     2    32
# 3     1     3    53
# 4     1     4    33
# 5     1     5    76
# 6     1     6    11
# 7     2     1    32
# 8     2     2    42
# 9     2     3    44
#10     2     4    12
#11     2     5    NA
#12     2     6    NA
#13     3     1    22
#14     3     2    12
#15     3     3    12
#16     3     4    67
#17     3     5    32
#18     3     6    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using `merge`.

```
df <- read.table(text = 
                "v1    v2    v3
                 1     1     79
                 1     2     32
                 1     3     53
                 1     4     33
                 1     5     76
                 1     6     11
                 2     1     32
                 2     2     42
                 2     3     44
                 2     4     12
                 3     1     22
                 3     2     12
                 3     3     12
                 3     4     67
                 3     5     32", header = T)
toMerge <- data.frame(v1 = rep(1:3, each = 6), v2 = rep(1:6, times = 3))
m <- merge(toMerge, df, by = c("v1", "v2"), all.x = T)
m

   v1 v2 v3
1   1  1 79
2   1  2 32
3   1  3 53
4   1  4 33
5   1  5 76
6   1  6 11
7   2  1 32
8   2  2 42
9   2  3 44
10  2  4 12
11  2  5 NA
12  2  6 NA
13  3  1 22
14  3  2 12
15  3  3 12
16  3  4 67
17  3  5 32
18  3  6 NA
```